# Chart series filtering

Tags: excel, reporting-services, charts

I have six series in my column chart for range of dates like 30 day period. This chart looks very congested:
[image: I have attached chart for reference]

Is there any way user can apply series filter on y axis and date filter on x axis to see the display of specific series on the chart at runtime?

I tried with report parameter. It does not work. Parameter selects whole chart to display or not. I do not know the exact way of doing that. Is there any chance in SSRS Chart itself to show filter at runtime so the user can edit the filter like one in Excel?

Comment: How do you want to drive the filtering?  I believe your options would be to either have specific parameters to get the user to request the series/dates to filter on, or to have a subreport that opens showing just the series you want to display.  Do either of these approaches sound suitable?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like the first option let the user filter the series based on their requirements.

Comment: @Jonnus , Have you had a chance to find the way of doing filtering based on selective series of the chart. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter on a parameter selected by the user you can follow this process.  Note that I am starting with a Chart like this based on the AdventureWorks database.  In this example I shall filter on the Region field only.

[image]

1. First you will need to define a new dataset to filter on.  Create a new dataset and set the query to be the equivalent of

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT   SalesTerritory FROM myView
   UNION 
   SELECT 'All' AS SalesTerritory
   ```
2. Now you need to create a new Parameter with values based on this Dataset.  I created one called `RegionFilter` with the Available values set to the values returned by your new dataset

   [image]

   And the default value set to 'All'

   [image]
3. Finally, you need to set the filtering on the Chart to be the result of the value selected for the parameter.  Right click on the Chart and choose Chart Properties… -> Filters

   Set the expression to be

   ```
   =iif((Fields!SalesTerritory.Value = Parameters!RegionFilter.Value) OR (Parameters!RegionFilter.Value = "All"), 1, 0)
   ```

   And the Value to be

   ```
   =CInt(1)
   ```

   This is essentially comparing the Region Filter Parameter value you have provided to either each record in the query, only allowing those that match, or, in the case of ‘All’ being selected, allowing all records.

When put together the report will look the same when first run, as the default value is set to `All`.  However when you chose a region the resulting chart will filter down accordingly.

[image]

I hope you find this useful and can adapt it for your requirements.  Let me know if you require further assistance

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try that today.

Comment: I have followed your steps here. My chart has the name of DataSet1. I have another dataset named DataSet2 for filtering. When I entered the expression for the filtering it shows error on the field. report items not linked to dataset because of different dataset for the chart. Error message: 'ReportItemExpression only refers to current dataset scope'. Could you please let me know which one I am missing here. Thank you very much

Comment: In The filtering expression you so not need to refer to dataset2, only the parameter you have set up such as Regionfilter in my example above

Comment: In my chart filter expression I have this statement=iif((Fields!Category.Value = Parameters!RegionFilter.Value) OR (Parameters!RegionFilter.Value = "All"), 1, 0). It throws error on 'Fields!Category' saying unknown collection member.  This is the field I am using for filtering dataset. Do I have to add this field to dataset for the chart? Thanks

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but does dataset1 have a field called Category?

Comment: I have complicated the simple thing to more complex. First I did pivot all Category and then show in the series. That's why I do not know where to set Category field.  Now I changed the query instead of pivoting I show the Category itself. Its working like a charm, Thanks . By default RegionFilter shows 'All' and chart says 'NoDataAvailable'. But all other categories ,chart shows values.  Could you please suggest where I have to fix to show the chart by default

Comment: Brilliant, if you found this useful Vote up/mark as answer/both

Comment: If the 'All' value is not showing any data it would imply the filter expression isn't quite right (though it looks OK in your comment above).  Ensure there are no extra spaces in any of the 'All' values (like when declared in the query or in the expressions) would be the first place to look.